# how to set fps for ffmpeg lavfi

Tags: ffmpeg

I made a 1-second sample video using ffmpeg lavfi with command below:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi  -i color=c=black:s=450x800:d=1  out.mp4
```

and I then used ffprobe to explore the video file , showing that it contains only 25 frames .

now I want to made a video that contains 30 frames in 1 second using ***lavfi*** , how do  I write the command ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most source filters have their own framerate option, including color.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi  -i color=c=black:s=450x800:r=30:d=1  out.mp4
```

The color filter options can be found at: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-colorchart_002c-colorspectrum_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc